# Expected 'tables' during Flyway migration

Tags: questdb

I'm moving over to QuestDB using the postgres connection and my flyway migration fails with a `FlywaySqlException`. I can see this in the logs:

```
SQL State  : null
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: expected 'tables' or 'columns'
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: expected 'tables' or 'columns'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are hitting is that the `CREATE` keyword [expects `table`](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/create-table), so you will get this if your flyway migration query is using

```sql
--will break
CREATE DATABASE <db_name>
```

Multiple databases are not supported by QuestDB as of yet, so [default postgres configuration](https://questdb.io/docs/develop/insert-data#postgres-compatibility) is:

```
database: qdb
```

Instead of creating multiple DBs, you can separate data out into multiple tables.